# Labels on iOS 8 simulator don't show up (but they work on iOS 7 simulator)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, uilabel

Sadly I no longer have a real iPhone to test, but I managed to use a friend's phone to make sure that labels are not working consistently between iOs 7 and 8.

I'm attaching two pictures of iOS 7 (working) and iOS 8 (not working). The problem that I'm experiencing is that labels are not showing up in the iOS 8 simulator. When I tried on the phone I could see something but the label width didn't resize automatically (which worked on iOS 7).

Have you experienced this issue? The code is literally the same. No changes from the version that I released for iOS 7.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

iOS 8
[image: iOS 8]

iOS 7

[image: iOS 7]

iPhone 6 Screenshot (ignore i18n)

[image: iPhone 6]

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *fuelLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *provinceLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *cityLabel;

-(void) didSelectChoice:(id)choice {
    [self updateUI];
}


-(void) updateUI
{
    BOOL hideSearchButton = YES;
    if (self.search.province && self.search.city && self.search.fuel){
        hideSearchButton = NO;
    }

    NSString *province = (self.search.province) ? self.search.province.province : @"";
    NSString *city = (self.search.city) ? self.search.city.city : @"";
    NSString *fuel = (self.search.fuel) ? self.search.fuel.fuel : @"";

    self.fuelLabel.text = fuel;
    self.provinceLabel.text = province;
    self.cityLabel.text = city;
    self.searchButton.hidden = hideSearchButton;
}
```

The code is not printing an empty string into those labels.

Comment: Post the code please, it could be a number of things...

Comment: Thanks, I attached some code.

Comment: Check auto resizing/positioning if you are not using Autolayout

Comment: I noticed that if you scroll down and then up again, when the TV Cell is rendered again, the data shows up. I tried adding a [self tableView reloadData]; but still doesn't work